# Getting a "ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity" when using metpy cape_cin function

Tags: python, arrays, valueerror, metpy

I'm trying to calculate cape and cin in a specified layer using metpy's cape_cin and get_layer functions. Im doing this for a RAP vertical profile that I access from the NCDC server, for 3 different parcel types (ML, MU, and SB). I get this error `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity` when I try to compute the mu and sb profiles, but not for the ml profile...even though i calculate the layers in the exact same way:

First, I have to create vertical profiles of pressure, temp, dewpoint, and heights, from the RAP vertical profile:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta   
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
from siphon.ncss import NCSS
import numpy as np
from metpy.units import units
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from metpy.calc import (dewpoint_from_relative_humidity, mixed_parcel, most_unstable_parcel, parcel_profile, pressure_to_height_std, lcl, height_to_pressure_std, get_layer, cape_cin)

year=2019
month=5
day=23
hour=0

cenlat = 34.91269
cenlon = -98.21048

time_start = datetime(year, month, day, hour, 0) #specified time
hour = time_start.hour
if hour < 10:
    hour = '0'+str(hour)
day = time_start.day
if day < 10:
    day = '0'+str(day)
month = time_start.month
if month < 10:
    month = '0'+str(month)

cat = TDSCatalog('https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/model-rap130-old/'+str(time_start.year)+str(month)+'/'+str(time_start.year)+str(month)+str(day)+'/catalog.html?dataset=rap130-old/'+str(time_start.year)+str(month)+'/'+str(time_start.year)+str(month)+str(day)+'/rap_130_'+str(time_start.year)+str(month)+str(day)+'_'+str(hour)+'00_000.grb2')
latest_ds = list(cat.datasets.values())[0]
print(latest_ds.access_urls)
ncss = NCSS(latest_ds.access_urls['NetcdfSubset'])

query = ncss.query()
query.variables('Pressure_surface').variables('Geopotential_height_isobaric').variables('Geopotential_height_surface').variables('Relative_humidity_isobaric').variables('Temperature_isobaric').variables('Dewpoint_temperature_height_above_ground').variables('Temperature_height_above_ground').variables
query.add_lonlat().lonlat_box(cenlon-2.1, cenlon +2.1, cenlat-2.1, cenlat+2.1)
data1 = ncss.get_data(query)
dlev = data1.variables['Geopotential_height_isobaric'].dimensions[1]
dlat = data1.variables['Geopotential_height_isobaric'].dimensions[2]
dlon = data1.variables['Geopotential_height_isobaric'].dimensions[3]

SFCP = (np.asarray(data1.variables['Pressure_surface'][:])/100.) * units('hPa')
hgt = np.asarray(data1.variables['Geopotential_height_isobaric'][:]) * units('meter')
sfc_hgt = np.asarray(data1.variables['Geopotential_height_surface'][:]) * units('meter')
Temp_up = np.asarray(data1.variables['Temperature_isobaric'][:]) * units('kelvin')
RH_up = np.asarray(data1.variables['Relative_humidity_isobaric'][:])
Td = (np.asarray(data1.variables['Dewpoint_temperature_height_above_ground'][:]) * units('kelvin')).to('degC')
T = np.asarray(data1.variables['Temperature_height_above_ground'][:]) * units('kelvin')

# Get the dimension data
lats_r = data1.variables[dlat][:]
lons_r= data1.variables[dlon][:]
lev = (np.asarray(data1.variables[dlev][:])/100.) * units('hPa')

# Set up our array of latitude and longitude values and transform to the desired projection.
flon = float(cenlon)
flat = float(cenlat)
crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
crlons, crlats = np.meshgrid(lons_r[:]*1000, lats_r[:]*1000)
trlatlons = crs.transform_points(ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=265, central_latitude=25, standard_parallels=(25.,25.)),crlons,crlats)
trlons = trlatlons[:,:,0]
trlats = trlatlons[:,:,1]
dlon = np.abs(trlons - cenlon)
dlat = np.abs(trlats - cenlat)
ilon = np.where(dlon == np.min(dlon)) #position in the dlon array with minimal difference between gridpoint lon and input lon
ilat = np.where(dlat == np.min(dlat)) #position in the dlat array with minimal difference between gridpoint lat and input lat

Tdc_up = dewpoint_from_relative_humidity(Temp_up[0,:,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]],RH_up[0,:,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]]/100)

p_sounding = np.sort(np.append(lev, SFCP[0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]]))
ind = np.where(p_sounding >= SFCP[0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]])[0][0]
hgt_sounding = np.insert(hgt[0,:,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]].magnitude, ind, sfc_hgt[0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]].magnitude) * hgt.units
T_sounding = (np.insert(Temp_up[0,:,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]].magnitude, ind, T[0,0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]].magnitude) * T.units).to(Tdc_up.units)
Td_sounding = np.insert(Tdc_up.magnitude, ind, Td[0,0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]].magnitude) * Tdc_up.units
p_skewt = p_sounding[p_sounding <= SFCP[0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]]]
hgt_skewt = hgt_sounding[p_sounding <= SFCP[0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]]]
T_skewt = T_sounding[p_sounding <= SFCP[0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]]]
Td_skewt = Td_sounding[p_sounding <= SFCP[0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]]]

AGLhgts = hgt_skewt[::-1]-hgt_skewt[-1]
```

Next, I create vertical profiles for each parcel type using mixed_parcel, most_unstable, and parcel_profile functions, and compute the pressure values for th etop and bottom of the layer I want to calculate cape_cin for (the LCL to LCL+2km):

```
ml_p, ml_T, ml_Td = mixed_parcel(np.flip(p_skewt), np.flip(T_skewt), np.flip(Td_skewt))
ml_profile = parcel_profile(p_skewt[::-1], ml_T, ml_Td)
ml_profile = (ml_profile - 273.15*units('kelvin')).magnitude*units('degC')

mu_p, mu_T, mu_Td, mu_index = most_unstable_parcel(np.flip(p_skewt), np.flip(T_skewt), np.flip(Td_skewt))
mu_profile = parcel_profile(p_skewt[::-1], mu_T, mu_Td)
mu_profile = (mu_profile - 273.15*units('kelvin')).magnitude*units('degC')

#Note: sbpcl_profile will have the exact same values of p_skewt, T_skewt, and Td_skewt in pprof below:
pprof = parcel_profile(p_skewt[::-1], T_skewt[-1], Td_skewt[-1])
pprof = (pprof - 273.15*units('kelvin')).magnitude*units('degC')

mllcl = lcl(ml_p, ml_T, ml_Td)
mllcl_h = pressure_to_height_std(mllcl[0]) - hgt_skewt[-1]

mulcl = lcl(mu_p, mu_T, mu_Td)
mulcl_h = pressure_to_height_std(mulcl[0]) - hgt_skewt[-1]

sblcl = lcl(p_skewt[-1], T_skewt[-1], Td_skewt[-1])
sblcl_h = pressure_to_height_std(sblcl[0]) - hgt_skewt[-1]

mllcl2000 = mllcl_h + 2*units('kilometer')
mulcl2000 = mulcl_h + 2*units('kilometer')
sblcl2000 = sblcl_h + 2*units('kilometer')
mllcl2000_p = height_to_pressure_std(mllcl2000)
mulcl2000_p = height_to_pressure_std(mulcl2000)
sblcl2000_p = height_to_pressure_std(sblcl2000)
```

With all of that computed, I use the get_layer function to create the arrays of pressure, temp, dewpoint, and parcel temp I need to compute cape_cin, and then go to compute the actual cape_cin values in the layer of interest:

```
ml_LCL_CAPE_layer = get_layer(p_skewt, T_skewt, Td_skewt, ml_profile[::-1], bottom = mllcl[0], depth = mllcl[0] - mllcl2000_p)
mu_LCL_CAPE_layer = get_layer(p_skewt, T_skewt, Td_skewt, mu_profile[::-1], bottom = mulcl[0], depth = mulcl[0] - mulcl2000_p)
sb_LCL_CAPE_layer = get_layer(p_skewt, T_skewt, Td_skewt, pprof[::-1], bottom = sblcl[0], depth = sblcl[0] - sblcl2000_p)

mlLCLCAPE = cape_cin(ml_LCL_CAPE_layer[0], ml_LCL_CAPE_layer[1], ml_LCL_CAPE_layer[2], ml_LCL_CAPE_layer[3])
muLCLCAPE = cape_cin(mu_LCL_CAPE_layer[0], mu_LCL_CAPE_layer[1], mu_LCL_CAPE_layer[2], mu_LCL_CAPE_layer[3])
sbLCLCAPE = cape_cin(sb_LCL_CAPE_layer[0], sb_LCL_CAPE_layer[1], sb_LCL_CAPE_layer[2], sb_LCL_CAPE_layer[3])

mlLCLCAPEcin = mlLCLCAPE[0] + mlLCLCAPE[1]
muLCLCAPEcin = muLCLCAPE[0] + muLCLCAPE[1]
sbLCLCAPEcin = sbLCLCAPE[0] + sbLCLCAPE[1]
```

The arrays for pressure, temp, dewpoint, and parcel temp for each of the 3 get_layer functions appear to be populated with the correct values, and these 4 arrays for each parcel type are all the same shape. The mlLCLCAPEcin calculation above gives the correct output (99.26 j/kg - which verifies when I plot it on a SkewT), but the exact same calculation for the MU and SB profiles give the error referenced above. I'm using Metpy v 1.1, and have tried to use a different location and output from a different forecast hour, and still run into the same issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'd start by double-checking what you actually get in layers for your `mu_LCL_CAPE_layer` and `sb_LCL_CAPE_layer`. My first guess is they're empty. If that doesn't point you in the right direction, be sure to edit your question to include a complete, self-contained, minimal version of your code to reproduce: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I double checked that the arrays are not empty for the mu and sb calculations. I've edited the question above, and included the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the area. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If I fix up your example code above (there were some name issues and some indexing issues) with:

```py
T_sounding = (np.insert(Temp_up[0,:,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]].magnitude, ind, Temp_up[0,0,ilat[0][0], ilon[1][0]].magnitude) * Temp_up.units).to(Tdc_up.units)
Td_sounding = np.insert(Tdc_up.magnitude, ind, Tdc_up[0].magnitude) * Tdc_up.units
```

I don't get any error running right now. If my fix above doesn't fix it for you, it would be helpful to know if you're running the latest MetPy 1.1.

Comment: I’m using MetPy 1.1. This runs for me too after that fix – however I realized I made a mistake in the post I made on 1/8 where I included the code. T and Td should have been included in the variables I was querying from the RAP data (they are for Temp/Dewpoint height AGL) – so the T_sounding and Td_sounding name/indexing issues were simply from me accidently forgetting them while posting a minimal version of the code (though those are probably still the issue in some way?). Sorry for all the confusion on this – I’ve updated the original question again to include this information.

Comment: Ok, that's reproducing for me, let me see...

Comment: I haven't had a chance to dig in, but I'm pretty sure it's a bug in MetPy. I've opened an issue and tagged it for the next release: https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/2315